# conditional operation on pandas column

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns

df1 =

```
name    col1
a       1
b       2
c       3
d       4
```

df2 =

```
name    col2
b       3
c       9
a       2
d       3
```

I want to compare names in both data-frames and multpily other two columns respectively. so the output would be like..

df3 =

```
name    col_new
a       2
b       6
c       27
d       12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for correct ordering with multiple by [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) and for extract original `col` is used [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df1['col_new'] = df1.pop('col').mul(df1['name'].map(df2.set_index('name')['col']))
```

For new DataFrame is uses [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df3 = df1.assign('col_new' = df1.pop('col').mul(df1['name'].map(df2.set_index('name')['col'])))
```

Or another solution with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and left join:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='name', how='left')
df3['col_new'] = df3.pop('col_x').mul(df3.pop('col_y'))
```

Comment: 1st solution works perfect. Thanks :)  2nd solution gives error "Can't assign to function call"

Comment: Also how to handle the result 'Nan' if the name is not present in df1. want to multiply the col with default value if name not found in 2nd df

Comment: @ppb then use parameter `fill_value` with default value , e,g 1 like `df1.pop('col').mul(df1['name'].map(df2.set_index('name')['col']), fill_value=1)`